# Doubts about derivative of $|x|$

Tags: calculus

We know that the derivative of $f(x)=|x|$ is $-1$, if $x\lt 0$ and $1$, if $x\ge 0$.

However for every $x\in \mathbb R$, the following holds

$f(x)=|x|=\sqrt{x^2}\implies f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x^2)^{-1/2}2x=1$.

So where is my mistake?

Comment: $f'(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \frac{x}{|x|} \ne 1$

Comment: You have essentially written $(x^2)^{-1/2}= 1/x$, but it's really $1/| x |$

Comment: It is false the $f'(0)=0$. The function $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Note also that when you say that the derivative of $|x| = 1$ for $x \geq 0$, it is actually for $x \color{red}{>} 0$.

Answer (score 4):

As you said
$$ f(x) = \sqrt{x^2} = |x| = \begin{cases} x, & \text{if } x\ge0\\ -x, & \text{if } x < 0, \end{cases} $$
then 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \frac{1}{|x|} = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x}, & \text{if } x > 0, \\ -\frac{1}{x} , & \text{if } x < 0. \end{cases}$$
Hence
$$ f′(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x^2)^{−1/2}2x=\frac{x}{|x|} = \begin{cases}1, & \text{if } x > 0, \\ -1, & \text{if } x < 0. \end{cases} $$

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, as you rightly point out.

But that means that $$(x^2)^{-\frac12}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \frac{1}{|x|}.$$

So, you cannot simplify $$x\cdot (x^2)^{-\frac12}$$ to $1$ (as you did), because it simplifies to $$\frac{x}{|x|}$$

Comment: So what about the rule $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user42912 That property holds, in general, for $b$ and $c$ integer, if $a \ne 0$.